# Show that $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\0 &\text{if }x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$ is discontinuous everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, sequences-and-series

Can any one help me to answer this question:

> Show that $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> 1 &\text{if }x\in \mathbb{Q} \\
> 0 &\text{if }x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}
> \end{cases}$$
>   is discontinuous everywhere.

Notice: use this theorem

> Let $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $c\in D$. Then $f$ is continous at $c$ if and only if, whenever $X_n$ is a sequence in $D$ that converges to $c$, then $f(X_n)$ converges to $f(c)$.

Thanks

Comment: Please give your questions more descriptive and precise titles - ideally, people should be able to understand what your question is just from the title. Please also do not use two `>` (i.e. `>>`), only one, and note that to put a line break, you need to end the line with two spaces.

Answer (score 10):

HINT: If $c$ is any real number, there is a sequence $\langle q_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of rational numbers converging to $c$, and there is also a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ of irrational numbers converging to $c$. Apply the theorem to these sequences.

Comment: hi Mr Brian can you please explain more about your answer is not clear to me thank you very much

Comment: @leena: I hate to say much more, because this is really very straightforward. Look at those sequences that I suggested: $f(q_n)=1$ and $f(x_n)=0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$, so what are $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(q_n)$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\;?$$ Can $f(c)$ be equal to both of them?

Answer (score 0):

Brian has given a good answer to you. I give you some notes, which maybe help you to understand more about the answer.

Note 1 that a function could more to one, **but it can not one to more.**

Note 2, $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$, and **all the irrational numbers, i.e., $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$ all also dense in $\mathbb R$.**

Note 3, $\mathbb R$ is **first countable.**

Comment: How are notes 1 and 3 related to the question? I seriously doubt OP knows what first countable means.

Comment: Of course! They are related to the question.