# How to show that $f$ is continuous only at $x=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, continuity

Can any one help me to answer this question:

> Assuming $$f(x)=\begin{cases} x &\text{if }x\in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 &\text{if }x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$
>
> show that $f$ is continuous only at $x=0$?

Notice: use this theorem

> Let $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and let $c\in D$. Then $f$ is continous at $c$ if and only if, whenever $X_n$ is a sequence in $D$ that converges to $c$, then $f(X_n)$ converges to $f(c)$

I hope someone can answer this question

Thanks

Comment: Which is it that you have problems with - to show that $f$ is continuous at $0$ or to show that is it discontinuous everywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:
To show that $f$ is continuous at $0$, use the easy result that $\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=0 \iff \lim_{x\to x_0}|f(x)|=0$ (the proof of this result is almost a tautology, and involves only unpacking the definitions.

To show that $f$ is discontinuous at any point $p\ne 0$, choose two sequence that converge to $p$, one consisting of rationals only and one consisting of irrationals only (you will need to justify the existence of such sequences). Then use the second result you quote.

Comment: This question is not the same as [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/354356).

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $|f(x)| \le |x|$, hence if $x_n \to 0$, then we have $f(x_n) \to 0$. Hence $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.

If $x \ne 0$, then let $q_n$ be a sequence of rationals converging to $x$, and let $\alpha_n$ be a sequence of irrationals converging to $x$. Then we have $f(q_n) = q_n \to x$ and $f(\alpha_n) = 0 \to 0$. Since $x \ne 0$, $f$ cannot be continuous at $x$ (since for any sequence $x_n \to x$ we would have $f(x_n) \to f(x)$).